# C++ code to calculate modulo of larger fibonacci number

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have written this code to calculate the modulo of a large fibonacci number using pisano period.
The code calculates the right pisano period when the value of period is small but when the period has to be a larger number (around 100), it gives the wrong pisano period.
here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long ll;
vector<ll> pisano(ll m){
        ll n1=0;
        ll n2=1;
        ll fib=0;
        vector<ll> pisanoseries;
        pisanoseries.push_back(0);
        pisanoseries.push_back(1);
        while(true){
                fib=n1+n2;
                n1=n2;
                n2=fib;
                pisanoseries.push_back(fib%m);
                if(pisanoseries[pisanoseries.size()-1]==1&&pisanoseries[pisanoseries.size()-2]==0){
                        pisanoseries.pop_back();
                        pisanoseries.pop_back();
                        break;
                }
        }
        return pisanoseries;
}
int main(){
        ll m;
        ll n;
        cin>>n;
        cin>>m;
        vector<ll>pisanoseries=pisano(m);
        int location=n%pisanoseries.size();
        cout<<pisanoseries[location];

}
```

Comment: number range overflow?

Comment: @Henry it gives wrong answer for 25 as well whereas the fibonacci of 25 is 75025. Should that cause a number range overflow?

Comment: The period for m=25 is about 100. So you need to check F_100.

Comment: @Henry right.So how do i fix it?

Comment: The fix is pretty easy, you can do all calculations modulo m: `fib=(n1+n2) % m`

Comment: @Henry that clarifies everything.Thanks